# Can't output contents of a text file to console using WriteConsoleOutputCharacter

Tags: c++, arrays, string, winapi, console

I want this code to output the contents of file.txt (two lines of *Lorem Ipsum*, 113 characters) to console.

```
#include <Windows.h>

void LoadFile(const char *filename="file.txt")
{
    FILE *stream;
    fopen_s(&stream, filename, "r+t");
    int size = 113;
    // filesize
    wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[size];
    // I'm using wchar_t because WriteConsoleOutputCharacter needs an LPCWSTR

    fread(screen, sizeof(char), size, stream);

    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, size, { 0, 0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
    fclose(stream);
}
```

The code does compile, however the actual output is just a string of squares:

[image: Little squares]

My understanding is that `fread()` will read the contents of `stream` and copy them into the buffer `screen`. I tried changing `sizeof(char)` to `sizeof(wchar_t)` and opening a file that is 100% wide chars (just a string of 113 **ж**'s, so 226 bytes) but got the same results.

I also tried to use `_wfopen_s` instead of `fopen_s`.

Comment: Does your file contain at least 113 wide chars, i.e. the file size is equal to or greater than 226 bytes?
`sizeof(wchar_t)`  was right.
Check returned value of fread. It must be exact 113 or do `size = fread(screen, sizeof(wchar_t), size, stream);`. Do not forget to free memory references by `screen`.
Finally you code is not C++ code.

Comment: @S.M. No, file.txt is actually 113 bytes, it contains just chars. However I tried to open another file (**wide.txt**) filled with 113 wide chars (so 226 bytes) and got the same results. The returned value of fread is 56 for **file.txt** and 113 for **wide.txt**.

Comment: You can't just *cast* the characters to wide characters, you have to convert them. Look at [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: If you save the file from Notepad with `Encoding: Unicode` your code should work. If it's UTF-8 it definitely won't, even though those `ж` characters will still take 2 bytes each.

Comment: @MarkRansom You're right, it does work now! For both files too. Thank you so much for your suggestion. I'm guessing that if I wanted to work with UTF-8 files I would have to use **MultiByteToWideChar** and convert the stream?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I told you. I'm sure there's guidance on how to use the function on this site.

Comment: The variable name `dwBytesWritten` is conceptually wrong. The API calls it `lpNumberOfCharsWritten`, but it's actually the number of UTF-16 elements written, which exceeds the number of characters written if the string contains UTF-16 surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies here:

```
fread(screen, sizeof(char), size, stream);
```

The problem is that you're telling `fread` to assume each cell is `sizeof(char)` bytes long, which is 1 byte, and you are then telling it to read "size" times the size of the cell, which means you are reading 113 bytes.

The issue is that you are trying to read ANSI characters into a wide-char array.
Also, your call here:

```
  WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, size, { 0, 0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
```

This specific function, `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` [as per microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputcharacter), has two variants, `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW()` and `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA()`but you are calling the macro version which based on your options, chooses which function is called, the two variants are different as the first variant is for wide-chars, and the latter is for ANSI chars.